# Mysql - Combine two select with distinct values

Tags: mysql

I m combining two select statements with union and i want distinct values with respect to the email column

```
(SELECT @ab:=@ab+1 as srno,email FROM tab, (SELECT @ab:= 0) AS ab 
where id > 1000
limit 1)
UNION
(SELECT @ab:=@ab+1 as srno,email FROM tab, (SELECT @ab:= 0) AS ab 
where id > 2000
limit 2)
;
```

I m getting the result for this query as

```
1   em1@domain.com
2   em1@domain.com
3   em2@domain.com
```

What is the way to get unique values with respect to the email column?  what i m expecting is this

```
1   em1@domain.com
2   em2@domain.com
```

Comment: You are using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`, which doesn't make sense.  What is the ordering for selecting 1 or 2 rows from each subquery?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, limit clause is just reduntant, i was testing out the query so i used the limit clause

Comment: What does the numbered column on the left actually represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ab is not initialised in the (SELECT @ab:= 0) in the second statement use another name

```
(SELECT @ab:=@ab+1 as srno,email FROM tab, (SELECT @ab:= 0) AS ab 
where id > 1000
limit 1)
UNION
(SELECT @ab1:=@ab1+1 as srno,email FROM tab, (SELECT @ab1:= 0) AS ab 
where id > 2000
limit 2)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT srno,email,ab
```

FROM(

(SELECT @ab:=@ab+1 as srno,email FROM tab, (SELECT @ab:= 0) AS ab

where id > 1000

limit 1)

UNION

(SELECT @ab:=@ab+1 as srno,email FROM tab, (SELECT @ab:= 0) AS ab

where id > 2000

limit 2))W

GROUP BY email;